# Can I Make My Google+ Profile Visible to Others in Google Game Services?

Tags: android, google-play-games

When doing an online quick match (i.e. finding random players), I want the game to know if it connected to me specifically. I would like to create a hidden achievement (or at least a notification if it seems too "out of reach" to achieve) if you play, defeat, or lose to me at my game. I personally think it would be awesome to know that I'm playing the creator and/or have defeated him. Is this possible? I always show up as Player_WXYZ due to privacy but I can't find a way to disable my privacy for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone can explain how to do what I was originally asking I will accept that answer, but I presume the real answer is no. As a workaround, since I can at least get info on the person logged in, I'm going to have my device send a particular message to the opponent to indicate that I am indeed the creator if it is my account logged in.